# python debugger interface for native code?

Tags: python, debugging, xdebug, jvmti

Is there any way to write debugging tools for Python that run in-process similar to the [JVM Tool Interface APIs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jvmti/)? It seems like all the Python debuggers I've run across are actually implemented through Python's introspection utilities (ie the debuggers themselves are written in Python which runs inside the process being debugged). Is that the only way to do it?

**EDIT:** It looks like PHP also provides similar in-process C bindings which dynamically-loaded debugging/profiling tools such as Xdebug can tie into. Libraries using these bindings are called `zend_extension`s.

Comment: This question is confusing because, you seem to be asking about a mechanism or a way of doing things rather than asking about a specific problem you have or what it is you'd like to accomplish.